# SQL result query in another query

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

i'm using innodb is foreign key for id_name-> name.id and id_street-> street.id
and i would like to get the name&number from name table depending on the street & zip from street table using the relationship table but i don't know the sql query i should use.

```
    Name                      Street                    Relationship
___________ _______      ______________ ____       __________________________
|id  |name | number|     |id  | street |zip |      |id | id_name | id_street |    
|____|_____|_______|     |____|________|____|      |___|_____________________|  
|1   | aaa | 11111 |     |1   | s1     |600 |      |1  | 1       |  1        |                   
|2   | bbb | 11112 |     |2   | s2     |600 |      |2  | 1       |  2        |
|3   | ccc | 11113 |     |3   | s3     |600 |      |3  | 2       |  3        |
```

should i use multiple query :

```
- 1)get the id of the street/zip (ex: s2 and 600 return=2 )
- 2)get the id of the name (1) from the returned id (2)
- 3) select name/number field from name id (1)
```

or it's possible to merge all the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT name.name, name.number FROM name
    JOIN relationship AS r ON name .id = r.id_name 
    JOIN street ON street.id = r.id_street
    WHERE street.street = "yourStreet" AND street.zip="1111";
```

Comment: That is the only information you have to put in that query. Everything else stays the same, independent of your street and zip.

Comment: constructive criticism... you should get in the habit of using tableOrAlias.ColumnName for your queries to prevent ambiguity of column origins.  It could also be a problem if keys by same name are in common tables.  You could get unexpected results.

Comment: Updated my answer. Not is uses "tablename"."columnname"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the results by applying multiple joins

```
SELECT 
       N.name,n.number
FROM 
       Name N,
       Street S,
       Relationship R
WHERE
       N.id = R.id_name
AND
       S.id = R.id_street 
AND
       R.id_street = 2 (Displays data only Street ID 2)
```

you can add more custom conditions to filter and select the required columns thru aliases